# 3D to 2D - moving camera

Tags: vector, 3d, projection

I'm trying to make a 3D engine to to see how it works (i love to know how things exactly work) .. I heard that they put the camera somewhere and move and rotate the whole world - that was easy to make the only hard thing was making a function to multiply matrices
but i want to move the camera and keep the world at it's position - i saw some people doing it and i actually prefer it .. when i tried to make it myself i faced a simple mathematical problem
to understand the problem i will convert 2D to 1D instead of 3D to 2D(same thing)
look at this picture:

[image: Figure]

Now i have a Camera position(x,y) and it's Vector (the blue point) From 0 to 1
And i made another Vector from the camera to the object and divided it by the distance to get a vector from 0 to 1 (the white point)
Now the distance from the two vectors (d) are the displacement that i need to draw a point on the screen - but the problem is "which direction" .. distance is always positive so i have to determine if the second point is on the right of the direction vector or on the left - it's very simple for the eye but it's very hard using codes

when i tried to compare (y2-y1)/(x2-x1) i got incorrect results when one vector is on a quarter and the other vector is on another quarter (quarters of the Coordinate Plane)

so how to compare those two vectors to see where it is according to the other vector?

i also tried atan2 and i got some incorrect results but i think atan2 will be slow for computers because i have to calculate 2 times for every 3D point
if there is an easier way tell me

i used many words to describe my question because i only know the simple words in english

Comment: nice description but you are missing a few details...
What graphics library are you using ? opengl / directx or i don't know ...

Comment: no library - just making it from scratch - that way i understand it better .. i only use a function to draw a line from one point to another .. the Vector function is handmade as well :-D

Comment: opengl/directx are the gateway to the graphics card, unless you want to talk to the graphics card yourself(not advised at all) you must use one of them(or vulkan/mantis/etc).